# How can I avoid text that is exceeding DIV's width limits

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div structure that uses "display: inline-block" and "position:absolute". This is !important and cannot be changed!

But.. In child's floated left div, my text is exceeding its width.

How can I avoid this behavior?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/s8a818vw/

CSS:

```
#main {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background:pink;
}

.sub {
    width:600px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:400px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.sub-text {
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:lime;
    overflow: none; 
}

.sub-img {
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    background:red;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">

    <div class="sub">

        <div class="sub-text">

            <h1>Header</h1>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sit amet tellus vitae nisi feugiat malesuada. Phasellus semper vehicula ante. Pellentesque ut finibus nisl. Cras tempus, eros ut aliquam mollis, metus diam efficitur neque, non pellentesque eros mi a felis. In lectus ipsum, rutrum at risus eget, faucibus sodales ipsum. Nam vel interdum libero. Donec ac lacus interdum, rutrum neque sit amet, vestibulum tellus.</p>

            <a href="#">My Link</a>

        </div>

        <div class="sub-img">img 1</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue here is that you've set `white-space: nowrap;` on `#main`. That's being inherited by your `p` tag and causing the text not to wrap.

Setting `white-space` to something like `normal` will cause the text to wrap as you'd expect.

```
.sub-text{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `#main`

Comment: Also remove `overflow:hidden' from `#main` and add it to `.sub`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: normal;`, This will wrap the text to the next line.

Your code should look like:

```
.sub-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Hope this helps!